# Hibernate Validator - optional validation depending on lifecycle

Tags: java, validation, hibernate-validator

Just started using Hibernate Validator.  I have a case where a bean's id is autogenerated when saved.  I'd live to validate the bean before the save.  At which time the id can be null.  However, when I want to update it the id must be notnull.

So the generic @NotNull on the field won't work because when I go to save it it will fail validation.

There are ways to work around this, but I was wondering if the spec or hibernate implementation have a standard way of doing this.  I'd like to not have any validation errors on save and no validation on update.

Such as applying a constraint but it's ignored unless implicitly named or something like that.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve that with [groups](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/5.1/reference/en-US/html_single/#chapter-groups).

```
public class MyBean {
    @NotNull(groups = UpdateBean.class)
    private Long id;
}
```

Validate without the `id`:

```
validator.validate(myBean);
```

Validate with the `id`:

```
validator.validate(myBean, UpdateBean.class);
```